# I'm trying to write a very standard date_trunc query in BigQuery (standard SQL) and it's not running

Tags: date, group-by, google-bigquery

I have only ever used SQL on a postgres warehouse (Redshift), so I didn't realize that BigQuery used a different version until now... Below is the query that I'm trying to get to run:

```
SELECT date_trunc ('month', c.created) AS month
     , COUNT (DISTINCT (c.id)) AS charges
FROM stripe.charges c
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```

And then here is the error message I receive:

> java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](100032) Error executing query job. Message: A valid date part name is required but found c.created at [1:29]

I've read about 15 different stack overflow pieces on bigquery date_trunc, but all of them are for more complex problems than mine... As a result, nothing I've tried has worked...

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_trunc

Answer (score 2):

You have to switch the order of the parameters of `DATE_TRUNC` and remove the quotes from `'month'`:

```
SELECT date_trunc (c.created, month) AS month
     , COUNT (DISTINCT (c.id)) AS charges
FROM stripe.charges c
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```